# How can I grab a URL string inside a directory?

Tags: javascript, string, url, directory

I'm using this code to grab Google's utm_campaign from the URL to insert it in a hidden form field:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
       if (pair[0] == variable) {
         return pair[1];
       }
     }
   }
   function onLoad() {
      var value = getQueryVariable("utm_campaign");
      var e = document.getElementById('keyword');
      e.value = value;
   }
   </script>
```

The code works great in the root URL but when I use it inside a subdirectory it stops working.

site.com/?utm_campaign=test - Works

site.com/directory/?utm_campaign=test - Does not work

How can I grab a URL string inside a directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should function exactly the same whether you are on the root url or in a subdirectory.

In your case (based on the example lined in your comment), it appears that the `onLoad` function is only getting run on your root url because the `body` tag is defined as `<body onload="onLoad()">`

In order to have the `onLoad` function executed on your subdirectory pages, you'll need to include `onload="onLoad()"` in your body tag on those pages as well.

Comment: Thanks @BananaNeil The subdirectory page does have the code and the element with the keyword id. I really don't know javascript, I found the script a long time ago but that now that I need to implement it in subdirectories it just won't work. Will providing a link to the project help? Thanks

Comment: Yes, a link to the project should help.

Comment: Yes! I totally missed that. Thank you very much @BananaNeil